# Product name limit in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.4, magento

I need to limit the length of the product name on the front end.

I am using Magento 1.4.2, can anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean with "limit"? Limit the length of the product name or ...?

Comment: Yes, Limit the length of the product name,in front end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the template files... Assuming you want to limit the name on the product view page, copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` to your theme in e.g. `app/design/frontend/interface/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.
In line 52, you have something like

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

You can change this in:

```
<h1>
    <?php
        // define the maximum length of the product name here
        $maxLength = 10;
        $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
        echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);
    ?>
</h1>
```

Please try to describe your question in more detail next time...

Hope this helps.

Comment: this code is not working i am also apply in base theme but its not working
    <?php
    $maxLength = 6;
        $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
        echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength);
    ?>

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Are you sure that the product view template is not overwritten anywhere else? If you e.g. write a "Test" behind the product name in the template, does it appear in the frontend?

Answer (score 5):

It's work for me

```
<?php $productName = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()); 
echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($productName, $length = 50, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. hope it should be working

```
$shortDescription = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description'); 

echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($shortDescription, $length = 50, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true);
```